# Properties of group with order p*q

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose p and q are different primes, and define a group A of group p$\times$q, which of the following is/are correct? 1, A is commutative. 2, It has four subgroups. 3, It is isomorphic with a transformation group of order pq.

For 2, I think it does have subgroups of order 1, q, p and pq. How about 1 and 3?

Comment: $S_3$ (of order 6, so $p =2, q = 3$) has one subgroup of order 3, and three subgroups of order 2, making for a grand total of 6 subgroups (including itself, and the trivial group). It's also non-abelian.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: nice example. In general, the dihedral group $D_{n}$ of order $2n$ is non-abelian and will have many more than 4 subgroups.